# How to go specific child of a ViewFlipper from a clickable ListView?

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

I have two activity, One of them(`FirstActivity`) which has a clickable  `ListView` with two items `item1` and `item2`. Another one(`SecondActivity`) which has `ViewFlipper` with two Child Layout `layout1` and `layout2`, I want to go `layout1` by clicking on `item1` of the `ListView`, My question is how I can do it? I have done so far

```
showPoemListLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           if(position == 0){
               viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
               viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.anamikaSV)));


           }

       }
   });
```

but it does not work at all :( null pointer exception appear after clicking on `item1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting NPE because you haven't started the `SecondActivity` yet.You can do this

In FirstActivity

```
showPoemListLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        if(position == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("POSITION_CLICKED",0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
});
```

Then in the OnCreate of your `SecondActivity`, after the `setContentView` call, do this

```
ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.your_viewflipper_id);
Intent intent = getIntent();
int POSITION_CLICKED = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION_CLICKED",0);
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(POSITION_CLICKED);
```

Just replace `R.id.your_viewflipper_id` with your `ViewFlipper` 's id.

[Developer guide on starting a new Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: I have got the appropriate answer, Thanks a lot @Veneet Raddy